# Can dbadmin be secured under nginx by using a rewrite rule to a 404?

Tags: security, nginx, database

I'm trying to redirect all 404 pages to a custom handler with NGINX.
I spent few hours to made the following rewrite in nginx but my question is: can it be a security breach?

```
location ~ ^/(?!(dbadmin)) { 
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/([^?]*)$ /index.php?_type_=handler&_route_=redirect&path=$1 break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you think this is unsafe?

Comment: Hours on that? save yourself time and do it properly. Host the dbAdmin on a different domain or a sub-domain on a different port other than 80, 8080 or 443, or use an htaccess that blocks all IP addresses except yours.